# using a variable in place of url in .load jquery

Tags: jquery, variables

is there a way to use .load with a variable replacing the URL, and specifying a portion of the remote document

something like:

```
item.find('.main_content').load( u "#product" );
```

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you concatenate the two strings, and make sure that the second string starts with a space:

```
item.find('.main_content').load(u + " #product");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url="item/list/"
$(document).ready(function(){
item.find('.main_content').load(url);// you can load a view
```

Or you can load a value in control as below:

```
var product="#product";
item.find('.main_content').load($(product).val());
```

});